# Subscript out of bound

Tags: r, shiny

I’m trying to format the output file from Vissim simulation to csv file. So I have 2 Fileinputs:

- FileInput 1 is for formatting the FZP file to CSV file, it can be uploaded multiple file but for now it can only upload 2 at max, but later on I would like the FileInput 1 can process more than 2 files.
- FileInput 2 is for merging the CSV file after converting the FZP file, because 1 run of VISSIM simulation can be multiple FZP files, so if I want to merge 2 runs or more I would like to use the FileInput 2 for merging it.

And my problem is in FileInput 1 because when I upload 2 files FZP it’s not causing an error, but when I only upload 1 file FZP it cause an error ‘Subscript Out of Bound’ even I already made a condition where the FileInput 1 in index 2 is Null then create new dataframe. Because, I’m trying to access individual file from the multiple uploaded file for calculating average of attributes in the FZP file by attribute called ‘VEHTYPE’.

So, how would I solve this?

```
#UI
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("File Input"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  tags$hr(),
  fileInput("file1",
            "Choose FZP files",
            multiple = TRUE),
  fileInput("file2",
            label="Upload multiple CSVs here",
            multiple = TRUE),
  uiOutput("column_1"),
  downloadButton("download", "Filter Table"),
  downloadButton("download1", "Aggregate Table")
),
mainPanel(
  uiOutput("tb")
))
))

#Server
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(data.table)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

data1 <- reactive({
inFile <- input$file1
if (is.null(inFile)) {
  return(NULL)
} else {
  inFile %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    do({
      df <- fread(input$file1[[1, 'datapath]]', skip="t;", sep = ";", header=T, stringsAsFactor = F)
    })
  }
  })

  data2 <- reactive({
  inFile <- input$file1
  if (is.null(input$file1[[2, "datapath"]])) {
  subData <- data1()
  df <- subData[0,]
  df
  #data1()
  } else {
  inFile %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    do({
      df <- fread(input$file1[[2, 'datapath']], skip="t;", sep = ";", header=T, stringsAsFactor = F)
    })
  }
  })

  output$column_1 <- renderUI({
  if (is.null(data1())) {
  return(NULL)
  } else {
  selectInput("column1", "Feature selection:", names(data1()))
  }
  })

  average1 <- reactive({
  #Processing data1
  subsetData1 <- data1()
  calAvg1 <- subsetData1[, c("VEHTYPE",input$column1)] 
  calAvg1 <- aggregate(calAvg1[, ncol(calAvg1)], list(VEHTYPE = calAvg1$VEHTYPE), mean)
  total <- sum(calAvg1[, ncol(calAvg1)])/length(calAvg1$VEHTYPE)
  dfTotal1 <- data.frame("Total", total)
  names(dfTotal1) <- c("VEHTYPE", input$column1)
  newDF1 <- rbind(calAvg1, dfTotal1)
  })

  average2 <- reactive({
  #Processing data2
  subsetData2 <- data2()
  if(is.data.frame(subsetData2) && nrow(subsetData2)==0){
    subsetData2
  }else{
    calAvg2 <- subsetData2[, c("VEHTYPE",input$column1)] 
    calAvg2 <- aggregate(calAvg2[, ncol(calAvg2)], list(VEHTYPE = calAvg2$VEHTYPE), mean)
    total <- sum(calAvg2[, ncol(calAvg2)])/length(calAvg2$VEHTYPE)
    dfTotal2 <- data.frame("Total", total)
    names(dfTotal2) <- c("VEHTYPE", input$column1)
    newDF2 <- rbind(calAvg2, dfTotal2)
    }
  })

  finalDF <- reactive({

  if(is.data.frame(average2()) && nrow(average2())==0){
  average1()
  }else{
  final <- rbind(average1(), average2())
  #average2()
  }
  #Merge all dataframe
  #finalDF <- rbind(average1(), average2())
  })

  data3 <- reactive({ 
  req(input$file2) ## ?req #  require that the input is available

  multiFile <- input$file2

  df <- rbindlist(lapply(multiFile$datapath, fread),
                use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
  as.data.frame(df)
  return(df)
  })

  output$original <- renderDataTable({
  data1()
  })

  output$filterData <- renderTable({
  finalDF()
  })

  output$multiData <- renderTable({
  data3()
  })

  output$download <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function(){
  paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
  },
  content = function(file){
  write.csv(get_table(), file,row.names = F)
  }
  )

  output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function(){
  paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
  },
  content = function(file){
  write.csv(data3(), file,row.names = F)
  }
  )

  output$tb <- renderUI({
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Original Data", dataTableOutput("original")),
            tabPanel("Filter Data", tableOutput("filterData")),
            tabPanel("Aggregate Data", tableOutput("multiData"))
  )
  })
  })
```

**FZP files look more or less like this:**

```
$VISION
* File: Y:\03_Studentische Arbeiten\VT\IDP\Windu\Test Simulation\test1.inpx
* Comment: 
* Date: 03.08.2017 09:32:43
* PTV Vissim: 9.00 [04]
* 
* Table: Vehicles In Network
* 
* SIMSEC: SimSec, Simulation second (Simulation time [s]) [s]
* NO: No, Number (Number of the vehicle)
* LANE\LINK\NO: Lane\Link\No, Lane\Link\Number (Unique number of the link or connector)
* LANE\INDEX: Lane\Index, Lane\Index (Unique number of the lane)
* POS: Pos, Position (Distance on the link from the beginning of the link or connector) [m]
* POSLAT: PosLat, Position (lateral) (Lateral position at the end of the time step. Value range 0 - 1:  0: at the right lane edge  0.5: middle of the lane  1: at the left lane edge)
* EMISSIONSCO2: EmissionsCO2, Emissions CO2 (Quantity of carbon monoxide [grams / sec])
* EMISSIONSNOX: EmissionsNOx, Emissions NOx (Quantity of nitrogen oxides [grams / sec])
* FUELCONSUMPTION: FuelConsumption, Fuel consumption (Fuel consumption [US liquid gallon])
* INQUEUE: InQueue, In queue (Returns if the vehicle is in queue. Queue is defined by speed and headway treshholds. (see queue definition))
* NUMSTOPS: NumStops, Number of stops (Number of stops (cumulative): all situations in which a vehicle comes to a standstill (speed = 0), except stops at PT stops and in parking lots)
* SPEED: Speed, Speed (Speed at the end of the time step) [km/h]
* VEHTYPE: VehType, Vehicle type (Select Vehicle type from the list box)
* 
* SimSec; No; Lane\Link\No; Lane\Index; Pos; PosLat; EmissionsCO2; EmissionsNOx; FuelConsumption; InQueue; NumStops; Speed; VehType
*
$VEHICLE:SIMSEC;NO;LANE\LINK\NO;LANE\INDEX;POS;POSLAT;EMISSIONSCO2;EMISSIONSNOX;FUELCONSUMPTION;INQUEUE;NUMSTOPS;SPEED;VEHTYPE
0.50;1;1;1;0.80;0.50;;;;0;0;41.70;100
0.60;1;1;1;1.96;0.50;;;;0;0;41.90;100
0.70;1;1;1;3.13;0.50;;;;0;0;42.16;100
0.80;1;1;1;4.31;0.50;;;;0;0;42.50;100
0.90;1;1;1;5.49;0.50;;;;0;0;42.91;100
1.00;1;1;1;6.69;0.50;;;;0;0;43.39;100
1.10;1;1;1;7.90;0.50;;;;0;0;43.92;100
1.20;1;1;1;9.13;0.50;;;;0;0;44.44;100
1.30;1;1;1;10.37;0.50;;;;0;0;44.96;100
1.40;1;1;1;11.63;0.50;;;;0;0;45.48;100
1.50;1;1;1;12.90;0.50;;;;0;0;45.99;100
1.60;1;1;1;14.18;0.50;;;;0;0;46.49;100
1.70;1;1;1;15.48;0.50;;;;0;0;47.00;100
1.80;1;1;1;16.79;0.50;;;;0;0;47.50;100
```

**Error**

```
Warning: Error in [[: subscript out of bounds
Stack trace (innermost first):
117: [[.data.frame
116: [[
115: fread
114: overscope_eval_next 
113: do.rowwise_df
112: do
111: function_list[[k]]
110: withVisible
109: freduce
108: _fseq
107: eval
106: eval
105: withVisible
104: %>%
103: <reactive:data2> 
 92: data2
 91: <reactive:average> 
 80: average
 79: renderTable 
 78: func
 77: origRenderFunc
 76: output$filterData
  1: shiny::runApp
```

Comment: Can you check on which line of the code you're getting that error?

Comment: Hi @Barbara , I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the assignment of the file to the data frame, I fixed a bit the code there.

Try changing the server code in the following way and let me know whether it works.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

data1 <- reactive({
inFile <- input$file1
if (is.null(inFile)) {
  return(NULL)
} else {
  inFile %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    do({
      df <- fread(input$file1$datapath, skip="t;", sep = ";", header=T, stringsAsFactor = F)
    })
}
})

data2 <- reactive({
inFile <- input$file1
if (is.null(inFile)) {
  return(NULL)
} else {
  inFile %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    do({
      df <- fread(input$file2$datapath, skip="t;", sep = ";", header=T, stringsAsFactor = F)
    })
}
})

output$column_1 <- renderUI({
if (is.null(data1())) {
  return(NULL)
} else {
  selectInput("column1", "Feature selection:", names(data1()))
}
})
```

Comment: Hi @Barbara , it cause another error `'input' must be a single character string containing a file name, a command, full path to a file, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or the input data itself` .
But, I don't have a **input$file2** based on your code. What I'm trying to do is to have 1 file input that can upload multiple file **then** I can access individual file to calculate average of attribute based on **input column** based on attribute called **VEHTYPE**. Hope that make a better understanding for you, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To convert .fzp files to .txt or .csv just use DOS command prompt. 
You can navigate to your folder and use the following syntax:
    ren *.fzp *.txt
or 
    ren *.fzp *.csv
after that, follow the steps on this page [reading from folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903673/reading-files-from-a-folder-and-despite-indexing-correctly-i-receive-a-error-i)
 and use read.csv with "skip= " to read your files.