# Reading files from a folder and despite indexing correctly, I receive a "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection" error

Tags: r, rstudio, read.table, file-read

I am trying to read files from a folder. 
I set the working directory and the target folder.

```
setwd("F://directory/SimulationOutputs/folder - Copy/")
spwfolder <- ("F:/directory/SimulationOutputs/folder - Copy/spws/")
spws <- list.files(spwfolder)
```

After this step, I check to see if it is getting it right:

```
 spws[1]
[1] "Cambridge2018_136.txt"
```

Next,  I want to read the first file:

```
spw<-read.table(spws[1], sep=";", row.names=NULL, skip = 8, fill = TRUE, 
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And I get this message:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition:
>   Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file
>   'Cambridge2018_136.txt': No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the working directory to `/folder - Copy/` but your files are in `/folder - Copy/spws/`.

Alternately, you could use `list.files` with `full.names=TRUE` so that `spws` will contain the full path to the file and then it wouldn't matter where your working directory is set.

Comment: Thanks,  @divibisan!  I will have to read from two different folders and that is why the parent folder is set as the working directory. I will have to loop through hundreds of files in each folder, I am not sure how I can set the wd to contain both folders. I will try the alternative option you suggested.

Comment: And.. your alternative worked! Thanks again, @divibisan!

Comment: Glad to help! If this answered your question, feel free to upvote and/or accept with the green checkmark under the voting buttons

Comment: I have upvoted you, but it is going to take a while till I get 15 reputations until the upvotes or anything by me is posted. :)

Comment: Don't worry about points or upvotes, they're not really important. But if this answered your question, you should accept the question by clicking the green checkbox under the voting arrows. Once you've accepted the answer, your question is marked as answered and it signals to future visitors that the answer *does* work.

Comment: I just did. Thanks!